# Precision of decimal computed columns in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, decimal, calculated-columns

We used to have the following field in database:

```
FieldA    decimal(19, 2)
```

We have changed the field to a computed field:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ADD FieldA AS FieldB * FieldC
```

Where:

```
FieldB    decimal(19, 2)
FieldC    decimal(19, 5)
```

The resulting new `FieldA`:

```
FieldA    (Computed, decimal(38,6))
```

The legacy code uses `FieldA`with the assumption that it has two decimals. Thus, the string translations do not apply formatting. As a result, with the new definition, `FieldA` is shown with six decimals, which is unacceptable.

Is it possible to modify the precision of the computed column (say, to keep the original type `decimal(19, 2)`) or do we need to add appropriate formatting to all the places that are displaying the value?

Rounding does not work:

```
ADD FieldA AS ROUND(FieldB * FieldC, 2)
```

Comment: `ROUND()` does not change the result data type. use `CAST() or CONVERT()` like `CONVERT(decimal(19,2), FieldB * FieldC)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST]
(
    [A] DECIMAL(19,2)
   ,[B] DECIMAL(19,5)
   ,[C] AS [A] * [B]
   ,[D] AS CAST([A] * [B] AS DECIMAL(19,2))
);

GO

SELECT *
FROM [sys].[columns]
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[TEST]');
```

[image]

Why? Check the [formula](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) of how decimal precision is set when operations are perform over decimal values.

[image]

So, we have:

```
[A] DECIMAL(19,2)
[B] DECIMAL(19,5)
[C] AS [A] * [B]
```

and the formula is:

```
p1 + p2 + 1 => 2 + 5 + 1 => 7
s1 + s2 => 19 + 19 = > 38
```

but:

> In multiplication and division operations, we need precision - scale
>   places to store the integral part of the result. The scale might be
>   reduced using the following rules:
>
> 1. The resulting scale is reduced to min(scale, 38 - (precision-scale)) if the integral part is less than 32, because it
>      can't be greater than 38 - (precision-scale). Result might be rounded
>      in this case.
> 2. The scale won't be changed if it's less than 6 and if the integral part is greater than 32. In this case, overflow error might be raised
>      if it can't fit into decimal(38, scale)
> 3. The scale will be set to 6 if it's greater than 6 and if the integral part is greater than 32. In this case, both integral part and
>      scale would be reduced and resulting type is decimal(38,6). Result
>      might be rounded to 6 decimal places or the overflow error will be
>      thrown if the integral part can't fit into 32 digits.

and from rule `3` the scale is capped to `6` and you get `DECIMAL(38,6)`. That's why you need to explicitly cast the result to your target decimal type.